# Error when using "whereNotIn" method [laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

whenever I run this query, to return data not in another table I get this error

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method whereNotIn does not exist
```

Query

```
  $shipment_data_unassigned = Shipment::all()->where('status','=', $rulesetname)
   ->Where('shipment_cycle', '!=', 'closed')
    ->whereNotIn('ccctadm.Shipment.id',$assigned);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `all()` it executes the query and returns a collection with the results. So when you chain more methods you're actually chaining on a collection rather than building up the SQL query. Collections have a `where()` that filters the already returned results (not in SQL), but they do not have a `whereNotIn()` method.

To do this all in SQL Remove the `all()` call and replace it with a `get()` at the end.

```
$shipment_data_unassigned = Shipment::where('status','=', $rulesetname)
    ->Where('shipment_cycle', '!=', 'closed')
    ->whereNotIn('ccctadm.Shipment.id',$assigned)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you it was that easy, can  you tell me the deference between get ()and all() methods ?  if  you have time.

Comment: @AhmadzIssa the `all()` method is a static method that is a shortcut to simply get every single record in the database for that model. You cannot add any constraints. Once you add constraints like `Shipment::where(...)`  You're now working with a querybuilder instance. In order to execute the query and get results you need to call `get()` on the query builder instance.

Comment: @AhmadzIssa When you do `Shipment::all()` Laravel will immediately execute `SELECT * FROM Shipment` and return a collection with all the shipments. a Collection in Laravel is basically a more powerful array and you can do `where()` on a collection to search through it, but it's all done in memory. To make the "where" clause go into the SQL query instead you need to put your constraints before Laravel executes the query. So `Shipment::where('status','=', $rulesetname)` will translate to `SELECT * FROM Shiptment WHERE status = ?`. In order to finally execute that query you use the `get()` method

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thank you very much. I appreciate that.